# AWS Log Insights query with string contains and return string value as alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have below query to get data from cloudwatch log :

```
  fields @timestamp, @user, @fileName, @fileType, strcontains(@message,'downloaded') or strcontains(@message,'unauthorized') as status
| parse @message /(?<@user>(?<=User\s).*(?=\shas))/
| parse @message /(?<@fileName>(?<=file\s).+(?=,))/
| parse @message /(?<@fileType>(?<=type\s).+(?="))/
```

I'm facing issue in selecting status column value.
If strcontains(@message,'downloaded') then I want to display status column value as 'Downloaded' and if strcontains(@message,'unauthorized') I want to display status column value as 'Unauthorized'.

Can someone provide input here to improve query to fetch desired results ??
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share examples of log events for both cases (downloaded and unauthorized)?